# Как сделать picturebox с закругленными краями?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать закругление `PictureBox`, а именно:
Я хочу сделать вот как, добавив фотку на `PictureBox`, и применив закругление. Фотография которая была добавлена, не как не страдала при закруглении, а страдал только сам элемент.

```
    public class PictureBoxEx:PictureBox
{
    private int radius = 20;
    [DefaultValue(20)]
    public int Radius
    {
        get { return radius; }
        set
        {
            radius = value;
            this.RecreateRegion();
        }
    }
    private GraphicsPath GetRoundRectagle(Rectangle bounds, int radius)
    {
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.AddArc(bounds.X, bounds.Y, radius, radius, 180, 90);
        path.AddArc(bounds.X + bounds.Width - radius, bounds.Y, radius, radius, 270, 90);
        path.AddArc(bounds.X + bounds.Width - radius, bounds.Y + bounds.Height - radius,
                    radius, radius, 0, 90);
        path.AddArc(bounds.X, bounds.Y + bounds.Height - radius, radius, radius, 90, 90);
        path.CloseAllFigures();
        return path;
    }
    private void RecreateRegion()
    {
        var bounds = ClientRectangle;
        bounds.Width--; bounds.Height--;
        using (var path = GetRoundRectagle(bounds, this.Radius))
            this.Region = new Region(path);
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        this.RecreateRegion();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы меняете Region, что правильно. Фотка при этом никак не страдает (имеется в виду Image/Bitmap). / Возможно, вам нужно обычный незакруглённый PictureBox поместить на закруглённую панель большего размера.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Помещал, не получается...

Comment: Что именно не получается? Ваш код создаёт закруглённый пикчабокс. Если на него поместить картинку - её углы, соответственно, не видны. Но сам Bitmap никак не меняется.

Comment: В крайнем случае, нарисуйте в графическом редакторе, какой внешний вид должен быть и покажите нам картинку.